Cannot set up a gitlab docker container with custom SSH-port
When setting up a container through docker compose, I can push to an empty repo over port 22, but I can't seem to customize gitlab to use a port of my choice.
This is a snippet of my docker compose, with some placeholders:
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8:latest'
    container_name: '<container_name>'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url '<external_url>'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2424
    ports:
      - '2424:2424'
...etc

I get:

ssh: connect to host docker port 2424: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

My guess is that the gitlab_rails-line in docker compose still isn't configuring gitlab to use port 2424 correctly, since when I open /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb on the container it looks like this:

### GitLab Shell settings for GitLab
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22

But even when I uncomment that row and change the port to 2424, followed by:

gitlab-ctl restart
gitlab-ctl reconfigure

I still get the same error.
AFAIK everything else is identical in these two cases (same ssh key on identical account on github and I am trying to push the same project through the same uri).
Any ideas on why this isn't working? Much appreciated.
EDIT:
I gave up and just used a 2424:22 port mapping instead, but I'll leave the question here in case someone is having the same problem. Maybe someone with experience will see what's missing right away.
